# Tampermonkey/Chrome: Mouseover, Ctrl+C → copy hyperlink (with original title)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, hyperlink, clipboard, tampermonkey

I need a script for chrome/tampermonkey wherein a hyperlink w/its entire original title is copied to the clipboard after hovering over that link and pressing ctrl+c. I'd be using the copied link to paste into microsoft office docs/etc. Can anyone provide a script? Thanks!

Comment: Don't just ask for other people to write your code for you. Provide a clear question, with context and code samples, if you want others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Tampermonkey script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Copy hyperlink using mouse hover + Ctrl + C
// @include     *
// @grant       GM_setClipboard

// ==/UserScript==

document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.code === 'KeyC' && e.ctrlKey && !e.altKey && !e.shiftKey && !e.metaKey) {
    const a = document.querySelector('a:hover');
    if (a) {
        var linkURL = a.href;
        var linkText = a.text;
        var myLink = '';
        myLink = myLink.concat("<a href='",linkURL,"'>",linkText,"</a>");
        GM_setClipboard(myLink, 'html');

    }
  }
})
```